# Dean's apportionment

Tags: algorithm

I would like to program Dean's apportionment. https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-deans-method-of-apportionment

Here is my code, but it is not converging into the right number of seats
Can someone help me?

```
statePopulation = {44., 225., 565.};
seats = 32;
quotas = statePopulation/Total[statePopulation]*seats
cond = 
  Table[
    If[quotas[[i]] == 0, 
      0, 
      Floor[quotas[[i]]](Ceiling[quotas[[i]]]/
        ((Floor[quotas[[i]]] + Ceiling[quotas[[i]]])/2))], 
    {i, Length[quotas]}]; 
hd = 
  Table[
    If[quotas[[i]] <= cond[[i]], Floor[quotas[[i]]], Ceiling[quotas[[i]]]], 
    {i, Length[quotas]}]; 
totalseats = Total[hd];
tbd = 
  Which[
    totalseats == seats, hd, 
    totalseats < seats, statePopulation/(Total[statePopulation]/(seats + 0.2)), 
    totalseats > seats, statePopulation/(Total[statePopulation]/(seats - 0.2))]
```

> `{1.6777, 8.57914, 21.5432}`